# Replace many strings by another string

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I want to run a shell script while ignoring some of the commands, because they need privileges. Commands like `insmod`. So I filter the script with this, and it works (those commands are replaced by `true`):

```
sed -e 's/command1/true/g' -e 's/command2/true/g' -e 's/command3/true/g' ... -e 's/commandN/true/g'
```

Is there a more concise way of expressing that?

With simple caracters, to change 'a', 'b', and 'm' into an 'x' I could do something like:

```
sed -e 's/[abm]/x/g'
```

or

```
tr abm x
```

(or its `tr abm '[x*]'` POSIX equivalent). But with strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `sed` is able to use the non-standard `-E` option to understand extended regular expressions, you may use

```
sed -E 's/string1|string2|string3/true/g'
```

The alternation with `|` is an extended regular expression feature not supported by basic regular expression of the type that `sed` usually supports.

The `sed` command above would replace any of the three given string even if they occurred as substrings of other strings (such as `string1` in `string10`).

To prevent that, also match word boundaries on either side:

```
sed -E 's/\<(string1|string2|string3)\>/true/g'
```

On macOS, you may want to use `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` in place of `\<` and `\>` to specify word boundaries.

---

As an aside, your `s/[a|b|m]/x/g` expression (now corrected in the question) would not only replace `a`, `b` and `m` with `x` but would also replace any `|` in the text with `x`.  This is the same as `s/[abm|]/x/g` or `y/abm|/xxxx/`, or the `tr` commands `tr 'abm|' 'xxxx'` and `tr 'abm|' '[x*4]'`.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for? With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/(command1|command2|command3)/true/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly, you could use `awk`:

```
awk '{gsub(/command1|command2|command3/, "true"); print}' < file
```

([`sed -E` is likely to be specified in the next major of the POSIX standard](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528) though, so it will probably spread to most implementations eventually).